# C++ How to make tables like at lua

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm working on a project and I really need to store my data like this:

```
my_table[id] = {x,y}
```

I have read about map and vector but I don't know how to make them store the data like I want

Can you give me any clues?

Comment: You can use the Lua C API to use Lua tables from inside C++.

Comment: Do you want to use Lua at all?

Answer (score 3):

```
// just an example, you can replace data with what fits you best.
struct data {
   int x_;
   int y_;
   data(int x, int y): x_(x), y_(y) { }
}

std::unordered_map<int, data> my_table;
my_table[id] = data(x,y);
```

You can find more about unordered_map [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Answer (score 0):

Make myTable an array of structs that has x and y as its first two variables. Then, you can use curly brace initialization like you want.

Comment: But the id that I have is not 0,1,2 etc they are random numbers that I have stored inside an array and I want to call the numbers to access mytable which is gonna contain x,y